# install Docker CE 17.03 on RHEL7

Tags: docker, redhat

Is it possible to install DockerCE in the specific version 17.03 on RHEL7 ?

- There is information here:

  - https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/rhel/#install-using-the-repository about the installing Docker on RHEL but there is no version info.
- and here with Docker 17.03 but only in Docker EE not **Docker CE**

  - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.0_Release_Notes/sect-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7.0_Release_Notes-Linux_Containers_with_Docker_Format-Using_Docker.html
    but they talk about Docker v 0.12

Comment: You might have to [handle the dependency on `container-selinux`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272827/docker-ce-on-rhel-requires-container-selinux-2-9)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-server-centos?tab=description), you can install Docker CE 17.03 (or future versions) on RHEL 7.3 64-bit via:

Set up the Docker CE repository on RHEL:

```
sudo yum install -y yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
sudo yum makecache fast
```

Install the latest version of Docker CE on RHEL:

```
sudo yum -y install docker-ce
```

Alternatively, you can specify a specific version of Docker CE:

```
sudo yum -y install docker-ce-<version>-<release>
```

Start Docker:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Test your Docker CE installation:

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

Comment: Are there any licensing concerns with attempting to manually install Docker CE on RHEL? Is this legally allowed?

Comment: This is not actually a manual install, but besides the point, non-enterprise Moby is released under the Apache 2.0 license, so there are no licensing issues with installing and using it. If you took code from enterprise and reused it, or used enterprise without paying for it, then there would probably be licensing issues.

Comment: Don't forget `sudo systemctl enable docker`, otherwise the service won't start automatically on boot.

Comment: My machine has the RPM `docker-1.12.6-16-e17.x86_64` installed, and I got error of `Error: docker-ce conflicts with 2:docker-1.12.6-16.el7.x86_64`.  There are two suggestions after the error message: 1. `You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem` and 2. `You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`.  What would you recommend?  Thanks!

Comment: @leeyuiwah You have to uninstall the old Docker RPM first. For some reason, Docker (company) forgot to use the `obsoletes` tag in its RPM metadata so CE does not automatically replace the older series like it should.

Comment: when i ran `sudo systemctl enable docker` it is giving me `Failed to start docker.service: Unit not found.` Has anyone got this?

Comment: Make sure you've configured proxy in `yum` before doing `sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
`

Comment: note that someone will need `sudo yum update -y` before installing docker

Answer (score 34):

Procedure for a disposable dev test RHEL 7.3. Never do this in production.

```
# pre-requisite for container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install policycoreutils-python

wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.107-3.el7.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -i container-selinux-2.21-1.el7.noarch.rpm

#Set up the Docker CE repository on RHEL:
sudo yum install -y yum-utils
sudo yum install -y device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
sudo yum makecache fast

# Install the latest version of Docker CE on RHEL:
sudo yum -y install docker-ce

#Start Docker:
sudo systemctl start docker

#Test your Docker CE installation:
sudo docker run hello-world

# configure Docker to start on boot
sudo systemctl enable docker

# add user to the docker group 
sudo usermod -aG docker jethro

# install Docker Compose:
# install python-pip
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

sudo yum install ./epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y python-pip

sudo pip install docker-compose

# upgrade your Python packages:
sudo yum upgrade python*
```

The above assumes you are NOT using a proxy. If you are, you will need to add `proxy=http://myproxy:myport` lines pretty much at the end of each block in each file under `/etc/yum.repos.d/`, or add it to `/etc/yum.conf`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: your solution perfectly worked! Thanks a lot! Question: why you are not recommending same process for PRD? then what will be right process for PRD?

Comment: You will want and need Docker support in production in particular for scalability issues.

Comment: The container-selinux part is outdated. Use: `wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.21-1.el7.noarch.rpm; rpm -i container-selinux-2.21-1.el7.noarch.rpm`

Comment: This is close, but the official AMI for RHEL 7 on AWS ships with xfs filesystem with d_type=0, and won't start for me. https://community.centminmod.com/threads/using-docker-on-centos-7-choose-ext4-over-xfs.12492/

Comment: Latest verion
`sudo yum install policycoreutils-python`

`wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.74-1.el7.noarch.rpm; rpm -i container-selinux-2.74-1.el7.noarch.rpm`

Comment: After spending all morning trying to get docker set up on a redhat7 machine with centos repo (due to rhel licencing restrictions), this has got me up and running. No idea what just happened, would be great if the magic here could be explained!

Answer (score 19):

For those who are facing below error:

```
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
       Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9
       You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
       You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

While installing docker on RHEL 7.3+ we need to execute:

```
    sudo subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
```

which will enable extra rpms to be installed on yum update.After this execute:

```
    sudo yum update
```

Then follow:
[Install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/)

This has worked for me.

Comment: Seems as of Docker 18.03+ it needs the additional dependency `pigz`- which is sadly not in _Extras_; but in EPEL ->  `yum install –y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`:(

Comment: Executing the `subsciption-manager` command, I get a connection refused error: "Network error, unable to connect to server. Please see /var/log/rhsm/rhsm.log for more information."

Answer (score 9):

INSTALLING DOCKER RHEL/CENTOS

1. Got To: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/

   **download:  docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm                  2018-06-08 05:48  19M 
   download:  docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm          2018-06-08 05:48  29K**

   **Upload to server**

   2. yum -y install docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
   3. yum -y install docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
   4. sudo systemctl start docker
   5. REF:
      [install Docker CE 17.03 on RHEL7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981114/install-docker-ce-17-03-on-rhel7)
      https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-39-installing-docker-ce-on-redhat-rhel-7x
      https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/rhel/#set-up-the-repository

Answer (score 2):

Well maybe you can acheive installing Docker CE 17.06 or 17.03 on RHEL 7.3, but Docker documentation is quite clear:

> Docker Community Edition (Docker CE) is not supported on RHEL.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ee/rhel/

Comment: Neither is running Doom on your coffee machine, but it's nice to have the option.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem running 7.x and I did the following:

```
yum install -y yum-utils

wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms

yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.55-1.el7.noarch.rpm

yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

yum install -y docker-ce

systemctl restart docker
```

With this you'll not fall on the pigz error

```
Error: Package: docker-ce-18.03.1.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: pigz
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Also **you need to keep an eye** on the ***container-selinux*** since i'm using a direct link to the version 2.55-1

Answer (score 0):

By following From @Matt Schuchard and @Akash Srivastava

combining their commands together I found below command lines working for me.

```
sudo yum install -y yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
sudo yum makecache fast
sudo subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
sudo yum update
sudo yum -y install docker-ce
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We had offline environment, so I figure out to install all required packages one by one.

- Run [online.sh](https://github.com/ElmCompany/airgap/blob/master/airgap-docker/rhel7/online.sh) script to download these packages.
- Copy these packages to your server `scp -r *.rpm my.server:/tmp`
- Go to your server , `cd /tmp`, then run [offline.sh](https://github.com/ElmCompany/airgap/blob/master/airgap-docker/rhel7/offline.sh) script.