# Docker CE on RHEL - Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9

Tags: docker, unix, rhel

I am trying to install `Docker CE` on `RHEL` using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981114/install-docker-ce-17-03-on-rhel7). This is my RHEL version:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
```

When I execute this:

```
sudo yum -y install docker-ce
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Package: docker-ce-17.06.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried using `--skip-broken` and `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` but again getting the same error. Please let me know how to resolve this issue and install Docker CE in RHEL 7.3.

Comment: If you want to just make it work (knowing that you are using an unsupported rpm), look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45033117/3370010

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The `container-selinux` package is available from the `rhel-7-server-extras-rpms` channel.  You can enable it using:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
```

Sources for the package have been exported to `git.centos.org`, too, so you could rebuild it yourself using `mock`:

- https://git.centos.org/summary/rpms!container-selinux.git

Comment: I dont have an active subscription. Any alternative way?

Comment: You can use `mock` to build the package from the [sources on `git.centos.org`](https://git.centos.org/summary/rpms!container-selinux.git). `mock` itself is in EPEL, but it probably depends on some packages from Red Hat Enterprise Linux you have not installed yet, so you need to cross-grade to CentOS first.

Comment: I get `Error: 'rhel-7-server-extras-rpms' does not match a valid repository ID.`

Comment: @prayagupd This looks like an unrelated subscription management issue. You should open a support case.

Comment: @prayagupd it's too late to respond but it's because you might not be using RHEL server edition you might be using workstation.

Comment: I fixed by installing selinux `sudo yum -y install http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch.rpm` on redhat/ amazon linux. You can find other packages as well at http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: this worked like charm, for those who unable to get the baseurl link for this repo:
`baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/$basearch/extras/os`

Answer (score 76):

Installing the Selinux from the Centos repository worked for me:

1. Go to http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/
2. Find the latest version for container-selinux `i.e. container-selinux-2.21-1.el7.noarch.rpm`
3. Run the following command on your terminal: `$ sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/**Add_current_container-selinux_package_here**`
4. The command should looks like the following `$ sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.21-1.el7.noarch.rpm`

**Note: the container version is constantly being updated, that is why you should look for the latest version in the Centos' repository**

Comment: any easy way to script something so it finds the latest version on it's own?

Comment: Why do we have package managers like YUM if this kind of version picking is required?

Comment: Samir, you really pointed me in the right direction.  I was able to get docker-ce 19.03 installed on RedHat 7.9 using a series of centos rpm installs.  Believe it or not it works.  container-selinux package is foundational to install containerd and docker-ce.

Answer (score 59):

Just install selinux latest version to fix it:
`sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.107-3.el7.noarch.rpm`

More versions at 
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/

Older versions of 2.9: 
http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/cern/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. To future googlers, copying and pasting what they have above almost certainly won't work since it's old at this point. Go to the more versions link and grab the latest version (copy link address).

Answer (score 26):

Error: Package: 2:container-selinux-2.74-1.el7.noarch
(rhel-7-server-extras-rpms)

Requires: selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-216.el7

Installed: selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.el7_5.6.noarch
(@rhel-7-server-rpms)

selinux-policy = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.6

#There is dependency issue with the container-selinux version

To fix this error on rhel 7.x I have performed the below things

1. yum install http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch.rpm
2. yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
3. yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
4. yum install docker-ce

Now start the docker service

Comment: yum install http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch.rpm was the only way to install container-selinux. Thank you!

Comment: It's important to remark that, before installing docker-ce, a yum update could be required depending on your version

Comment: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

Answer (score 11):

Docker CE is not supported on RHEL. Any way you are trying to get around that is not a supported way. You can see the supported platforms in the [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/#server). I suggest you either use a supported OS, or switch to Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 9):

You have already have container-selinux installed for version 3.7
check if the following docker-ce version works for you , it did for me.

```
sudo yum -y install docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:19.03.5-3.el7
```

Comment: this actually worked for me!  literally _none_ of the other answers did.

Answer (score 5):

Head to http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/ and get the link to the latest container-selinux package. In my case the link  was [http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.68-1.el7.noarch.rpm](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/)

Head to your terminal as root and run:

> yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.68-1.el7.noarch.rpm

After that you can proceed to install docker:

> yum install docker-ce

Answer (score 4):

To resolve the following error I was facing to install docker-ce on RHEL-7

```
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-18.09.5-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Please run following command before installing latest version of docker-ce

```
yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.68-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Once previous command runs successfully then install docker-ce with following command

```
yum -y install docker-ce
```

once installation is done then run

```
systemctl start docker
```

**Note : Run all these commands with root user**

Comment: please try http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.95-2.el7_6.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 3):

To update `container-selinux` I had to install `epel-release` first:

Add [Centos-7](http://mirrors.aliyun.com/repo/Centos-7.repo) repository

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo http://mirrors.aliyun.com/repo/Centos-7.repo
```

Install `epel-release`

```
yum install epel-release
```

Update `container-selinux`

```
yum install container-selinux
```

Comment: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found

Comment: It is moved to http://mirrors.aliyun.com/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9 on amazon ec2 instance(Rhel7)

I tried to add extra package rmp repo by executing
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras
but it works.
followed steps from https://installdocker.blogspot.com/ and I was able to install docker.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
yum install http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch.rpm
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer does not add any new information. This is already answered by someone else

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal when you leave moderation-related comments, you should really be more specific than "This is already answered by someone else". That's also not a valid reason; just because it's answered doesn't mean it's not allowed to add another answer, assuming it isn't blatant plagiarism and follows the general rules for SE answers.

Answer (score 2):

Simple one command to fix this issue.

```
yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.107-3.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 2):

DOCKER Ce is not officialy supported on REHL to fix that run the below commands

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.107-3.el7.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -i container-selinux-2.107.el7.noarch.rpm

wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/slirp4netns-0.4.3-4.el7_8.x86_64.rpm



#Set up the Docker CE repository on RHEL:
sudo yum install -y yum-utils
sudo yum install -y device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
sudo yum makecache fast
yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

#Start Docker:
sudo systemctl start docker
 
#Test your Docker CE installation:
sudo docker run hello-world
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update June 2019**

What a dogs dinner. Unfortunately, the other answers didn't work for me.

For the most part, the [official docker instructions](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-using-the-repository) for installing using a repository DID work.

```
sudo yum install -y yum-utils \
  device-mapper-persistent-data \
  lvm2
```

Followed by:

```
sudo yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

However, I had to modify the next command as follows (adding **--nobest**):

```
sudo yum install docker-ce --nobest
```

Finally, check the **docker client**:

```
docker --version
Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
```

Note also, the above works for standard RHEL AMI on AWS, but not for the Amazon Linux AMI type. May also find referencing [this github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/20) insightful.

Added bonus, I found the following additional commands helpful:

Start the **docker daemon**:

```
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

Give the current user (in my case `ec2-user` - check with `whoami`) rights to the docker group. This avoids running everything with sudo.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Now, logoff and login again as same user as before (in my case `ec2-user`).

At this point, everything should be working. Check the **docker daemon**:

```
docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

Comment: Something on Docker's side changed very recently.  They now require container-selinux 2.74.  This is blocking us from installing docker in centos7.4 now.

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS7 I had to follow the third install method, get-docker.sh
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-using-the-convenience-script

Answer (score 1):

The best way to resolve this one is.
Download the latest container-selinux  package from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/ into the VM or the Machine where docker needs to be installed.
Error : sometime it will ask for red hat subscription to download from repo.
we can do it manually with out subscription as below
Run the below command this  will install dependencies manually
rpm -i container-selinux-2.107-3.el7.noarch.rpm
then run the yum install docker-ce

Answer (score 1):

If we face issues in installing docker in an aws ec2 instance.
Follow the below steps :

```sh
sudo yum update -y
sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
sudo yum install docker
sudo service docker start
sudo systemctl enable docker
systemctl status docker
```

(link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

As with other answers, adding the "extras" subscribed channels to a CentOS 7 Spacewalk deployment solves this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error while installing docker in redhat 7.
Below are the steps that eventually worked. This should be applicable in centos 7 as well.

```bash
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/rhel/docker-ce.repo
sed -i 's~/rhel/~/centos/~g' /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
yum --noplugins install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
systemctl start docker
systemctl status docker
systemctl enable docker
```

Answer (score -1):

I followed many links including the official documentation, however it all ended up in this error:

```
Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The only way it worked for me is as follows (`yum upgrade` worked I guess):

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

yum upgrade docker-ce
```

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/20#issuecomment-312760808) link helped me to solve this issue

Here is the solution:
For centos:
try

```
sudo yum install --setopt=obsoletes=0 \
>    docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 \
>    docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch
```

For Rhel:

```
sudo yum install --setopt=obsoletes=0 docker-ce-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.x86_64.rpm docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```