# Unable to install Docker 17 on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

unable to install docker 17 on CentOs 7. In CentOS 7, how can I install docker?

I am trying to install a local docker.io registry on a CentOS 7 machine following the instructions here:
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/

```
       [root@ip-172-31-31-198 ~]#  yum install docker-ce
    Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
    amzn-main                                                                                                                                                             | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
    amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                          | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.7-3.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: containerd.io >= 1.2.2-3 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libseccomp >= 2.3 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: docker-ce-cli for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.13-3.1.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.7-3.el7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64
    ---> Package docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:19.03.7-3.el7 will be installed
    ---> Package libseccomp.x86_64 0:2.3.1-2.4.amzn1 will be installed
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
               Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
    Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
               Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
    Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
               Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
    Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
               Requires: systemd
    Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.7-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
               Requires: systemd
    Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
               Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
    [root@ip-172-31-31-198 ~]#
```

Answer (score 2):

Check please following link, shown bunch of solution, I hope it could help

[[Docker CE on RHEL - Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272827/docker-ce-on-rhel-requires-container-selinux-2-9/45287245][1])

Comment: Tried all the options. Getting same error -- Requires: selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-39