# Install docker for centos7.3 fail

Tags: linux, docker, centos7, yum

I want install the lastest verion of docker following with this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#install-using-the-repository).
But when i ran  `sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`. I got the following error:

```
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.4.4-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-nightly)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
           Available: 2:container-selinux-1.10.3-59.el7.centos.x86_64 (extras)
               container-selinux = 2:1.10.3-59.el7.centos
           Available: 2:container-selinux-1.12.5-14.el7.centos.x86_64 (extras)
               container-selinux = 2:1.12.5-14.el7.centos
           Available: 2:container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch (extras)
               container-selinux = 2:2.9-4.el7
           Available: 2:container-selinux-2.10-2.el7.noarch (extras)
               container-selinux = 2:2.10-2.el7
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-20.10.6-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
           Available: 2:container-selinux-1.10.3-59.el7.centos.x86_64 (extras)
               container-selinux = 2:1.10.3-59.el7.centos
           Available: 2:container-selinux-1.12.5-14.el7.centos.x86_64 (extras)
               container-selinux = 2:1.12.5-14.el7.centos
           Available: 2:container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch (extras)
               container-selinux = 2:2.9-4.el7
           Available: 2:container-selinux-2.10-2.el7.noarch (extras)
               container-selinux = 2:2.10-2.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

My OS is `CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)` . How should I handle such a situation? I have try to yum install container-selinux, but it is still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`yum install http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/cern/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.74-1.el7.noarch.rpm`

The version requirement of `container-selinux` is not satisfied. Please download and install the required version from [here](http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/cern/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/) in case you need another version.

Comment: It seems not work. 
`Error: Package: 2:container-selinux-2.74-1.el7.noarch (/container-selinux-2.74-1.el7.noarch)
           Requires: selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-216.el7`

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272827/docker-ce-on-rhel-requires-container-selinux-2-9/45287245). I hope it helps.