# Unable to download docker on linux vm

Tags: linux, docker

Not sure why docker is so difficult to setup on my cloud vm. I tried to run

`sudo yum install -y docker`

But I get the following unknown error:

`Error: Package: containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable) Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

Pretty sad

I tried to download the latest package by writting

`sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch.rpm`

But I get a similar error:

`Error: Package: 2:container-selinux-2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch (/container-selinux-2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch) Requires: selinux-policy-targeted >= 3.13.1-216.el7 Installed: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.7.noarch (installed) selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.7 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-166.amzn2.5.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-166.amzn2.5 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-166.amzn2.9.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-166.amzn2.9 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.1.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.1 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.2.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.2 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.3.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.3 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.5.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-targeted = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.5 Error: Package: 2:container-selinux-2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch (/container-selinux-2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch) Requires: selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-216.el7 Installed: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.7.noarch (installed) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.7 Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-166.amzn2.5.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.amzn2.5 Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-166.amzn2.9.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.amzn2.9 Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6 Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.1.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.1 Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.2.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.2 Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.3.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.3 Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.5.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.5 Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.7.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.7 Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-166.amzn2.5.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.amzn2.5 Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-166.amzn2.9.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.amzn2.9 Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6 Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.1.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.1 Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.2.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.2 Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.3.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.3 Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.5.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.5 Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.7.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.7 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-166.amzn2.5.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.amzn2.5 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-166.amzn2.9.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.amzn2.9 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.1.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.1 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.2.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.2 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.3.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.3 Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.5.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.5 Error: Package: 2:container-selinux-2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch (/container-selinux-2.119.2-1.911c772.el7_8.noarch) Requires: selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-216.el7 Installed: selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.7.noarch (installed) selinux-policy = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.7 Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-166.amzn2.5.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy = 3.13.1-166.amzn2.5 Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-166.amzn2.9.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy = 3.13.1-166.amzn2.9 Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6 Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.1.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.1 Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.2.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.2 Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.3.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.3 Available: selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.5.noarch (amzn2-core) selinux-policy = 3.13.1-192.amzn2.6.5 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share the exact OS version and name.
You can try running `uname -a` and post the output here.

Assuming from the error it is `CentOS`, as specified in the error the `container-selinux` version is too old on your VM, try updating it.

1. Go to [CentOS](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/) Packages.
2. Find the latest version of `container-selinux` and copy the URL package.
3. Run the following command:
   `sudo yum install -y <copied container-selinux URL>`

If it complains about dependencies on other libs, you would need to update those too.

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 is my os

Comment: Ok, did you follow the instructions here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html ?

Comment: No but this worked for me sudo yum -y install docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:19.03.5-3.el7

Comment: I tried the latter instructions in the link but reached the same error

Answer (score 1):

Hi the problem seems to be solved here:
[Docker CE on RHEL - Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272827/docker-ce-on-rhel-requires-container-selinux-2-9/45287245)

with using another Repo.

Regards

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate rather than posting an answer that's just a link to another question.