# How to know that docker installed in redhat is community or enterprise edition?

Tags: docker, redhat

Some person has install docker in my Redhat system . I want to know whether it is community edition or enterprise edition . How can i do so?

I know community edition is not for Redhat .

May be some person would have created centos.repo in Redhat and installed docker ce .

This is what

> docker version

gives

[image]

When i do

> "rpm -qif /usr/bin/docker"

[image]

Comment: That is neither CE nor EE. That is a version prior to both.

Comment: How can i confirm that 100% ?

Comment: It is version 1.12.  Any version <= 1.13.x was before both.

Comment: Please can you explain your line . who's version? who's before ? I am new to redhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that this is neither the Community Edition nor the Enterprise Edition.  Based on the version and build date you posted, it looks like a build from the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Extras channels (as the build time is *identical* to what is built into its `docker` client binary—but the time is different from the RPM build time, which confused me initially).

You should be able to double-check using

```
rpm -qif /usr/bin/docker
```

and compare the package signer with [the official Red Hat product signing keys](https://access.redhat.com/security/team/key).

Software provided in the [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Extras channels is fully supported by Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/extras).  (The difference from other channels is the update frequency, not the support coverage.)  In this sense, these builds are closer to the Enterprise Edition from Docker, Inc., because there is vendor support (unlike the Community Edition, which is, I think, unsupported).

Disclaimer: While I work for Red Hat, you need to review the agreements for yourself to determine support coverage etc., and contact customer support in case there are open questions.

Comment: It is from redhat extra channel https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2017-1620.html#Red Hat Enterprise Linux Extras (v. 7) . what Redhat extra do ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Would you please rephrase?

Comment: you said right .It is from redhat extra channel https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2017-1620.html#Red Hat Enterprise Linux Extras (v. 7) . what Redhat extra do ?  is it use for docker install ?

Comment: It is the version of `docker` commercially supported by Red Hat, with some customizations for use on Red Hat Enterprise Linux. I don't really use `docker` and do not know how it compares with the CE/EE versions from Docker, Inc.

Answer (score 6):

**With `docker version` command**

**CE** : Comunity edition
**EE** : Entreprise edition

So `17.06.0-ce` correspond to community edition

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:18:10 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:17:03 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

If you haven't *ce* or *ee*, it's because you have installed `docker.io` package, which is maintened by [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/docker.io). 
`Version: 1.12.3`

On Windows, you can also look `about docker` here :
[image]

**EDIT**

> Docker Community Edition (Docker CE) is not supported on RHEL.
>   So, you have Docker entreprise edition.

[See Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ee/rhel/#uninstall-docker-ee)

Anyway, there are [some ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981114/install-docker-ce-17-03-on-rhel7) to install docker-ce, but you will see docker community edition with docker version.

Comment: `Server Version` is also mentioned in `docker info`

Comment: If you haven't ce or ee, it's because you have installed docker.io package, which is maintened by Ubuntu.

Comment: How can i check that it is docker.io package.

Comment: I see you use Windows, check into docker parameters

Comment: Can you check about docker : https://i.gyazo.com/b8c92356d9c260fe67491d34696dc212.png

Comment: I asked question for Redhat.

Comment: `dpkg -s docker.io`

Comment: It is possible to install Docker CE on RHEL so don't assume he isn't running CE on RHEL.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute docker version. All before Docker version 17.03 did not have a -ce or -ee in the version.

`# docker version`

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   60ccb22
 Built:        Thu Feb 23 11:07:40 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   60ccb22
 Built:        Thu Feb 23 11:07:40 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```