# Docker swarm mode on RHEL

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, rhel7, docker-swarm-mode

I have been trying to run a single node docker swarm for testing on RHEL 7.6. `firewalld` is disabled and not running.  Services are running on an `overlay` network.  I noticed that I can't connect to the published port either from the host or outside.  This behaviour is consistent for a few RHEL instances I tried.  I do use docker swarm on Ubuntu 16.04LTS and 18.04LTS without any glitches.

Given below is my `docker info`

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 14
  Running: 3
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 11
 Images: 4
 Server Version: 19.03.3
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: fhewk7l15g42o36henpfigwjk
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: kegypzam66ehi6s50utrsff1l
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 1
  Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
  Raft:
   Snapshot Interval: 10000
   Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
   Heartbeat Tick: 1
   Election Tick: 10
  Dispatcher:
   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
  CA Configuration:
   Expiry Duration: 3 months
   Force Rotate: 0
Autolock Managers: false
  Root Rotation In Progress: false
  Node Address: 10.0.1.125
  Manager Addresses:
   10.0.1.125:2377
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
 runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
 Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 15.33GiB
 Name: rhel-test.dev.koopid.io
 ID: IM3X:THRY:FYUO:L7XI:VJW6:5B4Y:VZOX:YL43:E7WR:U5GM:3BQK:NLKP
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

And my `overlaynet`

```
[
    {
        "Name": "overlaynet",
        "Id": "4g4dphekzyshqpcp0fjfmc877",
        "Created": "2019-10-18T14:29:06.284905975Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "142c22a7e517f463f37c89cfb58dcde37f9529c9b469357b37868057be044e48": {
                "Name": "dbsvcs_redis.1.0lsxkr88eq89igid7w7ifk3wq",
                "EndpointID": "167fbdfb2146f09bb20c258fea52d9f8ca886cf1d264b1d8cd9169532c26b9db",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "2e70a7589f13c74be66149d5bbf9504b5b74aee1ad6711f82ec4b02011c00cc1": {
                "Name": "dbpg_postgresql-rw.1.9keeuowk9zk5e6f8bq5a0itij",
                "EndpointID": "44a2376b4d0d2bdb8787c9cc18726da140ca0f9a8e97e54a6a78b2206e10a13b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.6/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d9119bb3d605aa9b2df23985cd884afa941499d888937e3c34f4ec08dac14c73": {
                "Name": "dbsvcs_influxdb.1.ap5cg0se1rntdbsopxbm7whma",
                "EndpointID": "d2a5c093a0721291a114309ef1fd690510b03007fdaf83c8d77e00870a1568cd",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-overlaynet": {
                "Name": "overlaynet-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "2bdf0d2370856d9a4b2da1e86d65521585ffc89c778f5db1d3f4b2fd39da7c8b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:08",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.8/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "80ab8f4e3bcd",
                "IP": "10.0.1.125"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've the following services and as you notice, all of them publish one or two ports.

```
4j7p43udxkoc        dbpg_postgresql-rw   replicated          1/1                 myregistry/postgres   *:5432->5432/tcp
hu0wkspwc7j3        dbsvcs_influxdb      replicated          1/1                 myregistry/influxdb   *:8086->8086/tcp
dlte2nzg226x        dbsvcs_redis         replicated          1/1                 myregistry/redis      *:6379->6379/tcp
```

And you can see that port 5432 is open for INADDR_ANY on the host

```
tcp6       1      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

However, I can't connect to port 5432 from the host our outside.  `psql` client times out as if some firewall is blocking the connection.

I can see the following errors if I enable `firewalld`

```
firewalld[2809]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
firewalld[2809]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
firewalld[2809]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
firewalld[2809]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
firewalld[2809]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge -o docker_gwbridge -j ACCEPT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
firewalld[2809]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
firewalld[2809]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -nL DOCKER-INGRESS' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
firewalld[2809]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -nL DOCKER-INGRESS' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
firewalld[2809]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -nL DOCKER-INGRESS' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
firewalld[2809]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -nL DOCKER-INGRESS' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Is it something I should worry about?  Do I need to fiddle around with `iptables` on RHEL to get docker swarm working.  There are some reports to add docker control ports to `iptables` for multi-node cluster configuration.  My `iptable` configuration is something like this...

```
$ iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 82507 packets, 8110K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       30  5664 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2       30  5664 DOCKER-INGRESS  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3       30  5664 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
5        0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
6        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
7        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
8       14  4064 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker_gwbridge  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
9        0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker_gwbridge  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
10      16  1600 ACCEPT     all  --  docker_gwbridge !docker_gwbridge  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
11       0     0 DROP       all  --  docker_gwbridge docker_gwbridge  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 82105 packets, 8106K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER-INGRESS (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5432
2        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp spt:5432
3        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:6379
4        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp spt:6379
5        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8086
6        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp spt:8086
7       30  5664 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2       16  1600 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker_gwbridge !docker_gwbridge  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3       30  5664 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker_gwbridge  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3       16  1600 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       30  5664 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Appreciate some help/direction to get this working on RHEL as I'm stuck on this for the last couple of weeks.  Configuring and running `docker swarm` on Ubuntu was a breeze!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got it working finally.  I don't have a reasoning for all steps.  I also noticed that I can't connect to ports published by services from `localhost` and also `firewalld` rules get messed up at time which requires a reboot.  I'm still investigating these issues. I followed the [answer by Bertrand_Szoghy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981114/install-docker-ce-17-03-on-rhel7) to install `docker-ce` and related packages first.

1. `firewalld` or `ipchain` needs to be installed on the server. `firewalld` is recommended on RHEL 7 or later.
2. Open `docker swarm` ports using firewalld.  Follow the [tutorial here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-centos-7). Also, make sure to open ports required by your services. Reload firewall rules (`firewall-cmd --reload`)
3. Initialize swarm  (`docker swarm init`)
4. Create overlay network  (`docker network create --subnet 172.20.1.0/24 --driver overlay --attachable overlaynet`)
5. Join additional nodes to swarm manager.

I noticed that the firewall configuration is important before initializing `docker swarm`. I was not able to connect to published ports from localhost or using the host IP when I updated firewalld configuration after initializing `docker swarm`.  I'm not sure why this order matters though.

Currently I'm able to connect to published service port via the `swarm manager` IP address from swarm manager itself or from outside the host.  I'm still investigating what firewall rules to be added for connecting via `localhost`.